# How do I get two input values and add them together in php

Tags: php

// What is the easiest way get these two values, store them in $total and make $total = to $first + $second and echo it in the html?

```
<form action="testing123.php" method="get">
    1. <input type="text" name="first"><br> 
    2. <input type="text" name="second"><br>
 <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php 
$x = $_GET["first"];
$y = $_GET["second"];
$total = $x + $y;
?>
first: <?php echo $_GET["first"]; ?><br>
second: <?php echo $_GET["second"]; ?><br>
total: <?php echo $_GET["total"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your testing123.php file you need to change two lines.

```
$x + $y = $total;
```

to

```
$total=$x+$y;
```

Because according to rule, right hand side value is assigned to the left variable. You are assigning `$total` to `$x + $y` ,which makes no sense.

AND change

```
total: <?php echo $_GET["total"]; ?>
```

To

```
 total: <?php echo $total; ?>
```

Because `$GET` holds the form elements for you.$total is your local variable which holds sum of `$x` and `$y`. So you need to echo it directly. `$_GET["total"]` holds no sense as we are not having any form input with 'total' name.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you weren't aware, you can put backticks to mark `inline code`

Comment: @jakar back ticks? I am not aware about it.

Comment: @AmBhar, it's to the left of the 1 (on a U.S. keyboard). its the thing inside these parentheses: ( **`** )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <form action="testing123.php" method="get">
 1. <input type="text" name="first"><br> 
 2. <input type="text" name="second"><br>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>

<?php 
 $x = $_GET["first"];
 $y = $_GET["second"];
 $total = $x + $y;
?>
first: <?php echo $_GET["first"]; ?><br>
second: <?php echo $_GET["second"]; ?><br>
total: <?php echo $total; ?>
```

Your `$total` variable was declared like `$x + $y = $total` it need to look like `$total = $x + $y;`

Then at the end you were trying to pull the $total variable out of the `$_GET` array which it is not in. If you look at your url you can see the `$_GET` variables in it `http://example.com/index.php?first=2&second=3` and then in your script you add those variables together in the `$total` variable and that is accessed with just `$total`.

Comment: Please explain why your code block answers the question, because I can see that you switched `$_GET['total']` with `$total` and I know why, but OP and future visitors might not.

Comment: Yep, sorry I was in the process of explaining.